# How to make a list of the values of dictionary present in a list?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary

```
my_list = [{'Wheels': 1, 'Handle': 1, 'Service': 1},{'Wheels': 2, 'Forks': 1, 'Handle': 1, 'Service': 1}, {'Electronic': 1, 'Sensor': 2, 'Hydraulic': 1,}]
```

Required Output:

```
[[1, 1, 1],[2, 1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple Pythonic one-liner

```py
my_list = [{'Wheels': 1, 'Handle': 1, 'Service': 1},{'Wheels': 2, 'Forks': 1, 'Handle': 1, 'Service': 1}, {'Electronic': 1, 'Sensor': 2, 'Hydraulic': 1,}]
l = [list(i.values()) for i in my_list]
print(l) # [[1, 1, 1], [2, 1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 1]]
```

Comment: Even simpler: `map(dict.values, my_list)` ([half joking](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P7cyPiezuETBViG6Wj08IzU1p1jdSsFQR0HdIzEvJScVyglOLSrLTAbzanWQFBoB5dzyi7IJa1KoVnfNSU0uKcrPy0yGK8grzi@CGuNRmVKUWJoDlayN5Sooyswr0chNLNBIyUwu0StLzClNLdZRgLpYU/P/fwA) :-)

Comment: @Pychopath Well, print(map(dict.values, my_list)) will print <map object at xx>

Comment: @gajendragarg You didn't look at the demo I linked to, did you?

Comment: @I did. Copy paste that code and run into your Python IDE. :) Note: map function returns a map object and if you use the print function on it , it will print the map object value in your terminal.

Comment: @gajendragarg And did you not see the output there? It printed `[[1, 1, 1], [2, 1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 1]]`.

Comment: @Pychopath I saw. That's for Python2. Are you still using Python 2 on your machine? In python2, dict.values()  return a list of dictionary values, But in Python3+ it is not a list. Instead it is a view object.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242171/discussion-between-gajendragarg-and-pychopath).

Comment: @gajendragarg No, I don't have Python 2 on my machine anymore. Needing Python 2 is why I said I'm half joking. I thought that was clear.

Answer (score 0):

In python 3.7+:

```
my_list = [{'Wheels': 1, 'Handle': 1, 'Service': 1},
           {'Wheels': 2, 'Forks': 1, 'Handle': 1, 'Service': 1},
           {'Electronic': 1, 'Sensor': 2, 'Hydraulic': 1,}]


result = [list(d.values()) for d in my_list]
print(result)
```